# Function on XMLHttpRequest.upload progress event not firing on Safari/Firefox (works on Chrome)

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

I have a form on a Prestashop's website where users can upload files. Those files can be heavy sometimes so I needed a progress bar with a percentage displaying in real time.

I did it with the `<progress>`  tag and the XMLHttpRequest object.

Everything's working fine on Chrome but nothing happens in Safari and Firefox.

Here's the JavaScript code :

```js
function uploadFile(event){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

        xhr.open(
            'POST',
            event.currentTarget.getAttribute('action')
        )

        xhr.upload.addEventListener(
            'progress',
            fillProgressBar
        )

        xhr.send(new FormData(event.currentTarget))
    }

    const progressElement = document.body.querySelector('progress')
    const progressInformation = document.body.querySelector('#progress_information')

    function fillProgressBar({lengthComputable, loaded, total}){
        const progression = lengthComputable ? ((loaded / total) * 100).toFixed(0) : 0
        progressInformation.textContent = progression
        progressElement.value = progression
        
    }

    const customForm = document.body.querySelector('#custom_form');

    customForm.addEventListener(
        'submit',
        uploadFile
    )
```

When I test a `console.log('Hello')` in :

```js
xhr.upload.addEventListener(
    'progress',
    console.log('Hello')
    fillProgressBar
)
```

I can see it in the console, the problem is the function `fillProgressBar` who just never fires.

I have searched a lot on the Internet in vain. What can I do on this?

Comment: Have you tried to pass `event` to the function, and use it's properties?

Comment: I even tried this :
`function fillProgressBar(event) { console.log(event) }`
and nothing happen. The function isn't called.

Comment: Try this way `xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (e) => { fillProgressBar(e) } )`

Comment: It worked only 2 times out of around twenty times. But still the ```console.log(e)```appeared only 1 time and not as many times as the upload progress. (thanks a lot for the help btw)